# Multi-Index DataFrame - Adding a Row utilizing other rows

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Looking at how many tasks were created vs how many were completed each month.

I want to add a row to the multi-index table that shows the percentage of tasks completes for each task type.

Therefore for each Task (A,B,C,D,E) I would like there to be "Total", "Complete" and "% Completed" row (Complete row divided by Total)

Struggling to figure this out, any help appreciated!

Current table:

`Month                      June       July    August    September
Tasks  Des

A      Total                181.0     85.0     69.0     15.0
       Complete              33.0     10.0     0.0      0.0
B      Total                 13.0     12.0     5.0      1.0
       Complete               5.0      9.0     0.0      1.0
C      Total                137.0     89.0     78.0     22.0
       Complete              66.0     54.0     27.0     12.0
D      Total                629.0    203.0     174.0     51.0
       Complete             451.0    127.0     87.0     28.0
E      Total                135.0    100.0     86.0     24.0
       Complete              46.0     27.0     29.0      2.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape,so possible divide by rows, last reshape back by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

Last for correct ordering use [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html).

```
df1 = df.unstack(0)
df1.loc['% Completed', :] = df1.loc['Complete', :] / df1.loc['Total', :]
vals = ['Complete','Total','% Completed']
df1 = df1.stack().swaplevel(0,1).sort_index().reindex(vals, level=1)
print (df1)
                         June        July      August  September
Tasks Des                                                       
A     Complete      33.000000   10.000000    0.000000   0.000000
      Total        181.000000   85.000000   69.000000  15.000000
      % Completed    0.182320    0.117647    0.000000   0.000000
B     Complete       5.000000    9.000000    0.000000   1.000000
      Total         13.000000   12.000000    5.000000   1.000000
      % Completed    0.384615    0.750000    0.000000   1.000000
C     Complete      66.000000   54.000000   27.000000  12.000000
      Total        137.000000   89.000000   78.000000  22.000000
      % Completed    0.481752    0.606742    0.346154   0.545455
D     Complete     451.000000  127.000000   87.000000  28.000000
      Total        629.000000  203.000000  174.000000  51.000000
      % Completed    0.717011    0.625616    0.500000   0.549020
E     Complete      46.000000   27.000000   29.000000   2.000000
      Total        135.000000  100.000000   86.000000  24.000000
      % Completed    0.340741    0.270000    0.337209   0.083333
```

Another solution with select by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), division and create level of `MultiIndex` by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = (df.xs('Complete', level=1)
        .div(df.xs('Total', level=1))
        .assign(Des='% Completed')
        .set_index('Des', append=True)
        )

vals = ['Complete','Total','% Completed']
df1 = df.append(df1).sort_index().reindex(vals, level=1)
```